# Search inside vector of vectors

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a 2D vector that i have to check if a ID already have been defined. The struct look like this

```
struct ExchangeStruct1 {
    std::vector<int16_t>id;
    std::vector< ObjectType_enum>type;

    std::vector<void*>source;
    std::vector<void*>destination;
    ExchangeStruct1();
};
```

The vector is defined as following

```
std::vector<std::vector<ExchangeStruct1>> exchangeList;
```

Is it possebile to search for the id in the second level of the vector. I tried using

```
it = std::find_if(exchangeList.begin(), exchangeList.end(), [key](const ExchangeStruct1>& o) -> bool {return o.id == key; });
```

But it only search in the first level

Comment: `find_if` iterates over 1 container, to iterate over the inner container you need a second `find_if` in the comparison of the first. I suggest to write a function, which does the nested ranged for loops. It is more readable in my opinion.

Comment: @mch

I tried this but i cant get it to work
`
 std::vector<ExchangeStruct1>::iterator it;
 for (uint16_t i = 0; exchangeList.size(); i++) {
  it = std::find_if(exchangeList.at(i).begin(), exchangeList.at(i).end(), [id](const ExchangeStruct& o) -> bool {return o.id == id;  });
 }
`

Comment: `for (const auto & inner_vector : exchangeList) for (const auto & element : inner_vector) if (element.id == id) return true; return false;`

Comment: what do you expect the call to return? Do you only need to know if the ID is present? Is an iterator to the outer vector ok?

Comment: I need to know if the ID existed, if i can get the iterator of that position it whould be even better @463035818_is_not_a_number

Answer (score 3):

With [`ranges::join_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/join_view) this becomes trivial:

```
auto jv = exchangeList | std::ranges::views::join;
auto it = std::ranges::find_if(jv, [key](const ExchangeStruct1& o) {
                                       return o.id == key;
                                   });

if (it != jv.end())
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: ranges is not compatible with C++11

Comment: @MarcusKammarfelt right. for C++11 you can use [ranges-v3 library](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) which was the base for `std::ranges`. And even if you for any reason can't use that this answer is helpful to other usersand will become increasingly more helpful with time as C++20 ages.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to know if the `id` is present or not you can nest calls to `std::find_if`:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
struct foo {
    int id;
};
int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<foo>> exchangeList{ {{0},{1},{2}},{{3},{4}}};
    int target = 2;
    bool found = 
        std::find_if(exchangeList.begin(),exchangeList.end(),
                    [target](const auto& a){
                        return std::find_if(a.begin(),a.end(),[target](const auto& f){
                            return f.id == target;
                        }) != a.end();
                    }) != exchangeList.end();    
    std::cout << found;
}
```

However, this is a case where a handwritten nested loop is definitely more readable:

```
 bool find_id(const auto& exchangeList,int id) {
      for (const auto& row : exchangeList) {
          for (const auto& element : row) {
                if (element.id == id) return true;
          }
      }
      return false;
 }
```

This is also simpler to modify in case you do need an iterator to the found element. You'd just need to be careful to choose a sentinel to return when the element was not found. It cannot be `exchangeList.end()`, but you could return a `std::pair< iterator to outer vector, iterator to inner vector>` and return `{ exchangeList.end(), whatever }` when no element was found.